# Creative Cloud login window won't be visible

Tags: macos, adobe

I'm using El Capitan 10.11.6 and whenever I have to log in into Adobe Creative Cloud the login window stays hidden behind everything else. It wont show even using command+tab, neither clicking the icon on the Dock. I have to quit or hide every other app to reach it.

**Is this a known issue? Any insight on how to avoid this problem?**

Comment: What version of CC? I'm guessing compatibility issue, as El Cap is getting a bit old these days

Comment: The CC is the latest Adobe release, it is up to date. My IT technician says High Sierra is not good, so he wont upgrade our systems...